# Best way to create a Caldav endpoint URL for data collection to a DB?

Tags: caldav

I am looking to consume data that is shared via the icalendar protocol. In order to receive this data I need an end point URL to plug into this app that will begin feeding the endpoint URL data.

Ideally I'd like to scale this to a multi-tenant but to begin with I am building it just for myself.

So what is the best and easiest way to create an end point to consume that data?

I've googled to my hearts content but for the life of me can't find the right way. I've found an opensource CalDav server online.

No code yet just looking for a recommendation

Comment: To broad a question, it is unclear what you want to achieve and why searching doesn't provide the necessary entry points. 
Also, iCalendar is not a protocol, it is a data format.
This is a pretty good introduction into related things: http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/

Answer (score 0):

If it's your purpose to let people subscribe to a calendar by using their own calendar client and then collect data I would say running [sabre/dav with the CalDAV plugin](http://sabre.io/dav/caldav/) would be your best option as it stores it data in either SQLite or MySQL.